# Gaussian process with 2D feature array as input - scikit-learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, gaussian-process

I need to implement GPR (Gaussian process regression) in Python using the scikit-learn library.

My input X has two features. 
Ex. X=[x1, x2]. And output is one dimension y=[y1]

I want to use two Kernels; RBF and Matern, such that RBF uses the 'x1' feature while Matern use the 'x2' feature. 
I tried the following:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import Matern as M, RBF as R

X = np.matrix([[1.,2], [3.,4], [5.,1], [6.,5],[4, 7.],[ 9,8.], [1.,2], [3.,4], [5.,1], [6.,5],[4, 7.],[ 9,8.],[1.,2], [3.,4], [5.,1], [6.,5],[4, 7.],[ 9,8.]]).T

y=[0.84147098,  0.42336002, -4.79462137, -1.67649299,  4.59890619,  7.91486597, 0.84147098,  0.42336002, -4.79462137, -1.67649299,  4.59890619,  7.91486597, 0.84147098,  0.42336002, -4.79462137, -1.67649299,  4.59890619,  7.91486597]

kernel = R(X[0]) * M(X[1])
gp = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel)

gp.fit(X, y)
```

But this gives an error

> ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2, 18]

I tried several methods but could not find a solution. Really appreciate if someone can help.

Comment: Please make your example fully reproducible by explicitly including the relevant imports

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I edited the post. Appreciate if you can shed some light

Comment: What is the new `x = np.atleast_2d(np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)).T`??

Comment: Just now deleted it. That's for the prediction part. Right now I am just trying to fit the data to GPR. Thanks u

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `X` should not be a matrix, but an array of 2D elements:

```
X = np.array([[1.,2], [3.,4], [5.,1], [6.,5],[4, 7.],[ 9,8.], [1.,2], [3.,4], [5.,1], [6.,5],[4, 7.],[ 9,8.],[1.,2], [3.,4], [5.,1], [6.,5],[4, 7.],[ 9,8.]])

# rest of your code as is

gp.fit(X, y)

# result:

GaussianProcessRegressor(alpha=1e-10, copy_X_train=True,
             kernel=RBF(length_scale=[1, 2]) * Matern(length_scale=[3, 4], nu=1.5),
             n_restarts_optimizer=0, normalize_y=False,
             optimizer='fmin_l_bfgs_b', random_state=None)
```

That said, your kernel definition will not do what you want to do; most probably you have to change it to

```
kernel = R([1,0]) * M([0,1])
```

but I am not quite sure about that - be sure to check the documentation for the correct arguments of the [RBF](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels.RBF.html#sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels.RBF) and [Matern](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels.Matern.html#sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels.Matern) kernels...

Comment: Thanks alot desertnaut. I am trying as you suggested. gp.fit works now.

Comment: My main issue is how to specify that; RBF takes the 1 st feature set and and Matern takes the second. Still that issue is not solved. In the documentation of RBF and Matern, I cant find a  place to specify which coloumn of the input 2D array should be taken.

Comment: @QuantumGirl you cannot specify that directly, you'll have to do it indirectly via the `length_scale` argument. The idea behind my approach is that `[1,0]` means the 1st *column* and `[0,1]` means the second one (it's like indices); I am just not completely sure that this is the correct way...

Comment: Thanks  desertnaut, I will try  length_scale.

Comment: I understand. But as per my understanding length_scale is to specify a hyperparameter. Not the input dimension. This is my problem. Let see. If sci-kit is not flexible I can probably move to GPML.Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @QuantumGirl you are absolutely right that it is a hyperparameter; the real question is if in fact the specific *values* I have suggested effectively do the job... ;)

Comment: @desertnaut: and do they now? I find this rather confusing! :-)

Comment: It works great! @desertnaut do you know how to proceed with a `DotProduct` kernel? I would like to have a linear kernel for one feature and a RBF for the other. I used your method to specify the RBF but I don't know how to do it with `DotProduct`. Thanks!

Comment: @hadrienj I kindly suggest you open a new question with the details

Comment: @desertnaut here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60721298/gaussian-process-sklearn-how-to-use-a-different-kernel-for-each-feature